# Fast Bulk insert - return ID and other items

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2012

I have a C# console app which is inserting single rows into a SensorLog table, and returning the insertedId 
I then use this insertedId to insert/update other tables

The DB is now getting around 50,000 single row inserts a min (800-900 a sec) on the SensorLog table, and while the DB can seem to handle this when everything is running ok, there have been recent times where the servers inserting the data get saturated with network activity (they are also doing other things) response times are very slow - even dragging a window across screen is very slow on RDP connection...then things start to fail.

I now want to move to batch inserting every 1 min.
The database is very busy and 24/7, most queries are done against the LIVE data on the SensorLog table
The insert needs to be as quick as possible.
The current record size of the SensorLog table is around 6.5 billion rows

Here is an example of a row in SensorLog table:

```
Id: 60000000
DeviceId: 1234
SensorTime: 1/1/2020 12:00:00  
EventId: 1  
Reading: 34
```

Here is an example of the Sensors table which always needs latest record info (via update)

```
Id: 1
DeviceId: 1234
SensorOwner: 59
LatestRecordId:  60000000
LatestRecordTime: 1/1/2020 12:00:00
```

Here is an example of the SensorsEvents table which is inserted into if SensorLog.EventId > 1

```
Id: 1
DeviceId: 1234
Fk_SensorLog_Id: 60000000
AlarmThreshold:  500
UserComments: blah
```

In the 1 min period, each sensor might report 1 to 20 times, so i would need to bulk insert these into SensorLog table, but only update the Sensors table with the newest only (LatestRecordId/LatestRecordTime)
There could 22,000 unique sensors reporting in this 1 min period.

So to recap, I need to move from single insert to batch insert, while being able to update/insert into the other tables (with the ID)

Things i've considered

1. I've looked into bulk inserting at C# level and return the Id's to C#, however I need to somehow marry the inserted database Id with the original dataset in C# to then update the Sensors table and insert into SensorsEvents table. I'm not sure if this is possible, or how to do this....and the performance implications of this....probably a bad approach
2. I've also thought about inserting into a #TempTable and then having an agent etc which then bulk inserts into the SensorLog table and all the other tables.

I'm assuming option 2 seems to be the best here since everything can be done at database level without back and forth to other servers

To summarise, I have 2 questions

1. Given the info above, does this solution seem OK, or are there any other approaches I should consider?
2. Given the above, what is the fastest way to bulk insert, and return the inserted ID back to the original data set (#temptable) so I can then update/insert to other tables

I would welcome any other solutions/suggestions that I have not considered.
Efficiency and performance to be able to scale to much higher numbers is my main concern

Sql server 2017 enterprise.